# Done executing task "RdlCompile" -- FAILED Error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, report-viewer2012

When I run my code from Visual Studio 2015 it gives error and the build failed.

When I build or rebuild or clean the solution there is no error,
But when I run it by clicking on the Start button it failed. It is a desktop application.

I cannot see any error in the error list.

When I changed the Error log file verbosity from Minimal to Detailed, I can see following failure error in the output window.

```
2>Output file "obj\Debug\RdlCompile.compiled" does not exist.
2>Using "RdlCompile" task from assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91".
2>Task "RdlCompile" (TaskId:27)
2>  Task Parameter:
2>      Sources=
2>          Reports\ReportPreviewDetailsSubreport.rdlc
2>          Reports\Report Preview Details.rdlc
2>          Reports\Report Preview.rdlc
2>          Reports\Report1.rdlc
2>          Reports\Report_Graph.rdlc
2>          Reports\Report_NoData.rdlc (TaskId:27)
2>  Task Parameter:StateFile=obj\Debug\RdlCompile.cache (TaskId:27)
2>  Task Parameter:TimeStampFile=obj\Debug\RdlCompile.compiled (TaskId:27)
2>  Output Item(s): FileWrites=obj\Debug\RdlCompile.cache (TaskId:27)
2>  Output Item(s): FileWrites=obj\Debug\RdlCompile.compiled (TaskId:27)
2>Done executing task "RdlCompile" -- FAILED. (TaskId:27)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue in VS 2017.  Uninstall and reinstall of VS 2017 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue.

I was able to correct it by uninstalling the Microsoft RDLC Report Designer extension. Disabling it was not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I am not too late. I faced this notorious issue and able to fix it with following steps

1. Change output verbosity to Diagnostic (Under Tools – Options – Projects and Solutions – Build and Run, there’s the MSBuild project build output verbosity combo box)
2. Reinstalled Microsoft RDLC Report Designer extension from [MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001&ssr=false#review-details)!
3. Rebuild Solution.

I took references from other answers like  [visual studio 2017 community build fail without showing any error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646114/visual-studio-2017-community-build-fail-without-showing-any-error#)!

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017, re-installing the the vsix for RDLC Report Designer worked!  Spent 10 hours trying to figure this out.