# visual studio 2017 community build fail without showing any error

Tags: visual-studio-2017

this is a project I open and edit everyday recently

One day I can still compile, build, publish the project before i go lunch,

after i came back, its build fail and show error box build fail (There were build errors,would you like to continue and run the last successful build), but there is no error shown ( i didn't change anything except some string, and it is local project thus only me can edit it)

there is warning message but i dont know if it matter at all

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:
```

I wonder how can a solution die by itself suddenly and how can I trace and recover this solution (as mentioned, i was working on this project just before lunch)

Output

```
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Iing.WebApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Build started 4/12/2019 3:54:53 PM.
2>CoreClean:
2>  Deleting file "C:\Users\sammak\Documents\Projects\MODIST2017 - Copy\Iing.WebApp\obj\Debug\Iing.WebApp.csprojAssemblyReference.cache".
2>  Deleting file "C:\Users\sammak\Documents\Projects\MODIST2017 - Copy\Iing.WebApp\obj\Debug\RdlCompile.cache".
2>_HandlePackageFileConflicts:
2>D:\VS2017\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets(33,5): message NETSDK1041: Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.IO, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' and 'Platform:System.IO.dll'.  NETSDK1033: Choosing 'Platform:System.IO.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.2.0' is greater than '4.1.1.0'.
2>D:\VS2017\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets(33,5): message NETSDK1041: Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' and 'Platform:System.Runtime.dll'.  NETSDK1033: Choosing 'Platform:System.Runtime.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.2.0' is greater than '4.1.1.1'.
2>D:\VS2017\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets(33,5): message NETSDK1041: Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' and 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'.  NETSDK1033: Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.3.0.0' is greater than '4.2.1.0'.
2>D:\VS2017\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets(33,5): message NETSDK1041: Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' and 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll'.  NETSDK1033: Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.0.2.0' is greater than '4.0.1.0'.
2>D:\VS2017\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets(33,5): message NETSDK1041: Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' and 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'.  NETSDK1033: Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.0.2.0' is greater than '4.0.1.0'.
2>D:\VS2017\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets(33,5): message NETSDK1041: Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' and 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'.  NETSDK1033: Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.2.0' is greater than '4.1.1.2'.
2>D:\VS2017\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets(33,5): message NETSDK1041: Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' and 'Platform:System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll'.  NETSDK1038: Could not determine winner because 'Reference:System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' does not exist.
2>D:\VS2017\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.ConflictResolution.targets(33,5): message NETSDK1041: Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll' and 'Reference:System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL'.  NETSDK1038: Could not determine winner because 'Reference:System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL' does not exist.
2>
```

Comment: I'd restart vs, then clean and rebuild. If you still get no output in the Errors window, look instead in the Output window and ensure the output kind is set to build, see what you can see in there (there may be a lot of it)

Comment: nothing, this solution contains 2 projects. and output shown 1 is succeed, one is fail immedately (attached FYI)

Comment: i changed the build and run to display Normal detail in the outputs, it shown more messages, but non of it make sense for me. since i didn't change anything mentioned at there

Comment: i have tried to copy the same solution to other pc, using same visual studio 2017 community. its able to compile and build....... then i put the worked solution back to the issued IDE, it cant build

Comment: Reinstall it? ( I hate it as s solution, as it's so brute force, but had you done it days ago, things might well be fixed already

Comment: i doubt it must work since the issed platform contain more reference ( lower version visual studio), the new platform is clean

Comment: the actual thing that scared me is i didnt change anything, but it suddenly fail to build. which is something i had never experienced before lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Microsoft already deals with that problem and working on a fix. Also there seems to be a workaround (I have not tried it yet)
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001&ssr=false#review-details

Comment: the fix does work in the review section. at all it is the microsoft bug due to the update they installed without notification at all. Its really crazy

Answer (score 0):

Same problem,

```
1>Build FAILED.
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    0 Error(s)
```

So, I search in output windows for **failed**, then I found this

```
1>Task "RdlCompile"
1>Done executing task "RdlCompile" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "RunRdlCompiler" in project "foo.vbproj" -- FAILED.
```

make sure you have this option: output verbosity = detailed,

> options / build and run / "MSBuild project build output verbosity" = detailed

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: In my case, o RdlCompile was an automatic update and started the problem, so , I install VS 2019 and RdlCompile again.